# RewriteCond/RewriteRule with case-insensitive and trailing slash functionality?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got problems with the following two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1.html [L]
```

Goal: Redirecting "domain.tld/test/" (only if test.html exists) so that it outputs the contents of "domain.tld/test.html".

- How to make this case-insensitive: "domain.tld/Test" -> domain.tld/test.html **
- How to make it accept a trailing slash: "domain.tld/test/" should work, too

Thanks!

** I couldn't get RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower to work, any help appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close as this is nowhere near a programming question. This is more fit for system administration and thus should be posted to serverfault.com

Comment: I searched before posting. There are over 30 pages of similar questions on SO. Please don't close me!

Answer (score 1):

Use [NC] for case insensitive checking.

See here for the trailing slash issue: [Mode Rewrite; with/without trailing slash on end of url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080495/mode-rewrite-with-without-trailing-slash-on-end-of-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/${tolower:$1}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1.html [L]
```

Furthermore [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) can only be used in the server configuration or virtual host context but not in a .htaccess file. So you need to define the rewrite map there.