# How do I remove a trailing "/" from a URL using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

How would I go about removing the `/` from the end of a URL using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the following to the .htaccess in the root of your domain. Replace yourdomain.com with your actual domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# remove trailing slashes from all urls except root domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+)/$
RewriteRule . http://yourdomain.com%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to turn off `DirectorySlash` otherwise things will get redirected back to having a trailing slash. Try something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L]
```

If you have other rewrite rules in your .htaccess file, you may need to find an appropriate place to insert these rules.

Comment: Here's a very similar question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080495/mode-rewrite-with-without-trailing-slash-on-end-of-url