# Redirect url rule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my `.htaccess` how I can redirect this type of url

`http://example.com/v1/login/`

to this

`http://example.com/v1/login` (without the final slash) ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080495/mode-rewrite-with-without-trailing-slash-on-end-of-url

Try checking out their answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RedirectMatch ^/v1/login/$ /v1/login
```

This will redirect **/v1/login/** to **/v1/login** .

Answer (score 0):

To remove a trailing slash using `.htaccess` you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before you test this. But it will leave you with your desired URL of: `http://example.com/v1/login`.