# Redirect including BLANK or /

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess code that works perfectly with any string...

http://nano:8888/abc/123/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nano.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

However it doesn't redirect when the URL is:

http://nano:8888/ or http://nano:8888

What modifications do I need to correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mode Rewrite; with/without trailing slash on end of url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080495/mode-rewrite-with-without-trailing-slash-on-end-of-url)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` will trigger if the requested URL is not an existing directory but the root URL would presumably be mapped to a root directory.

Comment: @MCMXCII I don't think that's the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FallbackResource`

```
FallbackResource /nano.php
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#FallbackResource

Comment: Worked perfectly! Much appreciated.

Comment: glad i could help, can you mark this as the answer please ? :-)